# How do I write this linq command to an equivalent delete SQL query?

Tags: sql, linq, query-optimization

I haven't written SQL in many years and now I'm working on a little more "performance hungry" site. 
Could someone please help me convert this to a delete SQL command?

I have a bunch of these so helping me with this one would sort out a lot for me, thanks!

I got this far:

```
Delete FROM [DbName].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels] 
WHERE  ...
```

Linq select command:

```
var allRatingListObjects = from row in ctx.RatingListTriangle
                           where
                              (row.To1Id == myToid && row.To2Id == theirTradeObjectid)
                               || (row.To2Id == myToid && row.To3Id == theirTradeObjectid)
                               || (row.To3Id == myToid && row.To1Id == theirTradeObjectid)
                           select row;
```

Update: Here is the working solution I went for:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
                ("delete TBL from RatingListTriangleModels TBL where ( TBL.To1Id = @MY_ID and TBL.To2Id = @OTHER_ID ) or ( TBL.To2Id = @My_ID and TBL.To3Id = @OTHER_ID ) or ( TBL.To3Id = @My_ID and TBL.To1Id = @OTHER_ID )", cn))
            {
                // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MY_ID", myToid));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("OTHER_ID", theirTradeObjectid));
                var no = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: but that linq doesn't delete anything?

Comment: @Jodrell, Well I guess this is why he stucked...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should delete the records you specify in your linq-statement but you need to replace `@YOUR_ID` and `@OTHER_ID` with the corresponding ids you have.

You can do this with `SqlParameter`. [Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

```
delete from [DbName].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels] TBL
where ( TBL.To1Id = @YOUR_ID and TBL.To2Id = @OTHER_ID )
   or ( TBL.To2Id = @YOUR_ID and TBL.To3Id = @OTHER_ID )
   or ( TBL.To3Id = @YOUR_ID and TBL.To1Id = @OTHER_ID )
```

Comment: Aside the Exception I'm getting you did answer my actual question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the rows that that linq selects with TSQL you could do

```
DECLARE @p0 int;
DECLARE @p1 int;
SET @p0 = <some integer>;
SET @p1 = <some other integer>;


DELETE
            [DbName].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels]
    WHERE
            ([To1Id] = @p0 AND [To2Id] = @p1)
        OR  
            ([To2Id] = @p0 AND [To3Id] = @p1)
        OR
            ([To3Id] = @p0 AND [To1Id] = @p1);
```

Of course you'll probably want to pass the statement to [`ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) on your context and pass the ids as a parameters, then .Net will wrap this in a call to `sp_executeSql` for you. This will protect from injection attacks, give you the benefits of query plan reuse and the flexibility of direct TSQL manipulation.

I would caveat my answer, a simple operation like this would problably be performed equivalently in linq without any of this additional complication.

Comment: The OP's question has **two** distinct `INT` values (`myToId` and `theirTradeObjectId`) - your answer only provides a single value, which probably won't do ...

Comment: @Jodrell It needs to be **delete from**, not just **delete**

Comment: @Viper, pretty sure the [FROM] is optional http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx